# How to use async function and export it correctly with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios

My question is about correctly implementing an async function to fetch data. I've a function called `_getData()` and I'm calling it on the `componentDidMount()` of a screen. But when server response is slow, switching to this screen is getting slower. So I would like to use async function for fetching data. But I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Is that a correct approach? I can't be sure if it works async or not.

Here is my `Api._getData()` code:

```
const _getData = async () => {
    return await axios.get("http://blabla.com/someservice", { params: someParamDataHere });
};

export const Api = {
    _getData
};
```

and on SomeScreen.js, I also have loadData() function which calls the function above and does state updates.

```
loadData() {

    Api._getData()
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ myData: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
    });
}
```

in **componentDidMount()** function of the same screen I'm calling this `loadData()`  function directly.

Now, is it enough to declare Api._getData() as async and using await in it, or should I change some trigger functions too?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: it would be same if you return simply the promise (`return axios.get("http://blabla.com/someservice", { params: someParamDataHere })`) from that `_getData()` function and that makes more sense to me actually.

Comment: Thank you @AneesIjaz May you please explain the reason?

Comment: well there is no point to do that except extra code. if you remove the `async` and return the promise itself it would do the same job. (As you are already resolving that promise in `componentDidUpdate`).

Comment: @AneesIjaz so to make this call async, should I change anything in componentDidUpdate too? or without using async/await, is it already async because of promise?

Comment: yes it is already async without that async keyword and await. you just have to remove the async keyword from function and remove await keyword. The request will be async.

Comment: I suggest you to read the difference in here https://javascript.info/async

Answer (score 2):

instead of async await use promises

```
export const getRequest = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    api
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        handleReponse(response)
          .then((errorFreeResponse) => {
            resolve(errorFreeResponse);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(handleError(error));
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correct while retrieving in load Data . What you can do more is try more syntactical sugar of es6 by using async await in loadData , hence

```
    loadData = async() =>{
    try{
    let response = await Api._getData();
    this.setState({ myData: response.data });
    } catch(err){
    console.log(error.response);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts